# CAMLprim, CAMLexport, CAMLextern

Tags: ocaml, bytecode, primitive

Where can I find the complete list of OCaml primitives implemented in C?
Is it enough to `grep 'CAMLprim' <ocamlsourcetree>/byterun/*.c`, or I have to look for `CAMLexport` and `CAMLextern` too, or what else?

(note: looking for `external` declarations in .ml,.mli files is not enough, because I need also all `caml_*` primitives referred by bytecomp/translcore.ml for special `%someide` externals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
ocamlrun -p
```

to get the full list of primitives available in the default runtime.

Comment: Oh, never been easier! Just now, I've seen that the primitive list printed by ocamlrun -p is defined in prims.c, which is built on-the-fly by Makefile in <ocamlsrctree>/byterun looking for CAMLprim. Thanks.